# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'io' when initializing tensorboard SummaryWriter

Tags: python, pytorch, tensorboard

I'm encountering an issue while trying to utilize `torch.utils.tensorboard.SummaryWriter` with PyTorch. I'm training a DCGAN in torch and despite not directly importing or using TensorFlow in my code, I receive the following error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Gebruiker/PycharmProjects/BobRossGAN/train.py", line 47, in <module>
    writer_real = SummaryWriter(f"logs/real")
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\tensorboard\writer.py", line 247, in __init__
    self._get_file_writer()
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\tensorboard\writer.py", line 277, in _get_file_writer
    self.file_writer = FileWriter(
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\tensorboard\writer.py", line 76, in __init__
    self.event_writer = EventFileWriter(
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\summary\writer\event_file_writer.py", line 73, in __init__
    if not tf.io.gfile.exists(logdir):
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\lazy.py", line 65, in __getattr__
    return getattr(load_once(self), attr_name)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'io'
```

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
import torch
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter

# other imports and code

writer_real = SummaryWriter(f"logs/real")
```

I can post my full code, but the error gets thrown on the `SummaryWriter` initialization.
I'm not sure why this error keeps persisting, I have tried downgrading to lower versions of pytorch, tensorflow and tensorboard, without much success. I've seen answers to similar questions include downgrading tensorboard to 1.15, but this also does not work for me.

Does anyone know how to address this error?
I'm using `torch==2.2.0` and `tensorboard==2.13.0`.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a file of your own named `tensorflow.py` in the module search path? That's often the cause of this kind of error. You may be able to see it in the file names in the full traceback (which you might want to include in the question).

Comment: I tested you code with python 3.10.13 and it worked. Is it possible a python upgrade?

Comment: I'm using Python Python 3.8.6, so I will try upgrading and see if it works

Comment: This does not seem to be working still